# Using Skobbler in AngularJS directive: 'Map container is already initialized.'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, skmaps

Using a directive to render the Skobbler leaflet:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('skm', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var map = L.skobbler.map('skm', scope.skm);

            // ....
        }
    }
});
```

This directive is used on different routes/partials in a similar way:

```
<skm id="skm"></skm>
```

Version info:

- Skobbler 2.0
- AngularJS 1.2.16

When moving from page 1 to page 2, no problem. However, going back to page 1:

```
    Error: Map container is already initialized.
```

I've tried storing the map object and using *map.remove()*, which removes the error but stops the map from rendering.

**FIXED**: See my answer below. (Use unique ID's in each partial and grab those)

Comment: Suggestion: If you create a JSFiddle or Plunker demonstrating the problem it might make it easier to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fixed:** Simply put a unique ID in each partial and grab the ID in the directive, then create the leaflet with this ID.

Partial 1:

```
<skm id="skm1"></skm>
```

Partial 2:

```
<skm id="skm2"></skm>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('skm', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var map = L.skobbler.map(attrs.id, scope.skm);

            // ....
        }
    }
});
```

**What didn't work:**

- replacing the outerHTML with original HTML on directive $destroy (directive didn't play well)
- map.remove() (Skobbler didn't care)
- Shouting profanities at the Skobbler library (Skobbler didn't care)

Answer (score 0):

Skobblerjs is a "thin" fork of leafletjs so (most likely) the error comes from the leaflet logic and not the skobbler logic.

There are some other mentions of this error, see of any of following are of help to you:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/xDNcNBAZq8o
http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/540/leaflet-maps

If not - then include a jsfiddle or plunker example so that we're able to debug